# 'useState' value is empty

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to fetch data from an API based on the year parameter with the initial year set to 2020. The components are on the same .jsx page and exported to App.js. When I try to log "search" it returns an empty object.

```
export default function Rank() {
    const [ search, setSearch ] = useState(2020)

    console.log(search)

    return (
        <main>
            <div>
                <SearchBar onSubmit={setSearch} />
            </div> 

            <div>
                <FetchTable />   
            </div>
        </main>
    );
}
```

I've removed some unrelated code in the FetchTable function but basically, it should return a table with data of the selected year.

```
function FetchTable(search) {

    console.log(search)

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`exampleapiurl?year=${search}`)
```

```
function SearchBar(props) {
    const [ innerSearch, setInnerSearch ] = useState();
    return (
        <div>
            <input
                aria-labelledby="search-button"
                name="search"
                id="search"
                type="search"
                value={innerSearch}
                onChange={(e) => setInnerSearch(e.target.value)}
            />
            <button 
                id="search-button" 
                type="button"
                onClick={() => props.onSubmit(innerSearch)}
            >
                Search
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are missing passing a `search` prop to `<FetchTable />`. Voting to close a unreproducible or caused by typo.

Comment: Now it's returning undefined.

Comment: Now *what* is returning undefined. Please be more specific about any issues.

Comment: Search is returning "undefined" when I console.log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `search` parameter to the `FetchTable`, and get it from the props. See comments in code.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React

function Rank() {
    const [search, setSearch] = useState(2020)

    return (
        <main>
            <div>
                <SearchBar onSubmit={setSearch} />
            </div> 

            <div>
                {/* pass search to FetchTable */}
                <FetchTable search={search} />
            </div>
        </main>
    )
}

function FetchTable({ search }) { // get search from the props
  useEffect(() => {
      // fetch(`exampleapiurl?year=${search}`)
      console.log(search)
  }, [search]) // useEffect should depend on search

  return (
    <div>{search}</div>
  )
}
        
function SearchBar({ onSubmit }) {
    const [innerSearch, setInnerSearch] = useState(''); // set an initial value to the state, so the input would be controlled
    
    return (
        <div>
            <input
                aria-labelledby="search-button"
                name="search"
                id="search"
                type="text"
                value={innerSearch}
                onChange={(e) => setInnerSearch(e.target.value)}
            />
            <button 
                id="search-button" 
                type="button"
                onClick={() => onSubmit(innerSearch)}
            >
                Search
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Rank />,
  root
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: @plshelp  Accept this answer so that others know the question has been answered.